# Can't Detect UIView Children Touches Correctly when Parent UIView is Being Animated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm working on an iOS app.

I have a UIView that is being animated. It keeps moving from left to right.

This view has several UIView children. They move within their parent when this is being animated.

When I try to capture user touches on the children (by using a UITapGestureRecognizer), it doens't work as expected. It sort of detect some touches on the children, but not in the position where they currently are.

I've been struggling with this for a while now. Any ideas about how to solve this? I really need to detect which children the user is touching.

Thanks!

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];

    // Check every child subview
    for (UIView *tickerItem in self.subviews)
    {        
        // Check collision
        if ([tickerItem.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:touchLocation])
        {
            MKTickerItemView *v = (MKTickerItemView*)tickerItem;
            NSLog(@"Selected: %@", v.title);

            // This button was hit whilst moving - do something with it here
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a piece of code for quick help

Comment: I already did. Thanks @Stanley... "self" is the parent UIView, and its subviews are "ticketItem"'s.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `UIViewAnimationOptions` value...

`UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`

You can use this in the `[UIView animateWithDuration...` code.

This will enable the touch.